# Unable to use ScalaTest

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class MyTestSuite extends FunSuite {

}
```

I got the following message in Intellij IDE:

> class MyTestSuite must be either declared abstract or implement
>   abstract member '$bang$eq$eq(right: T): TripleEqualsInvocation' in
>   'org.scalactic.TripleEqualsSupport'

However, according to [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/), there is no need to implement anything. Please advice, thanks

Comment: I suspect it might be due to the empty body. Can you try to copy the example from the top of the page you link to, i.e., the class `ExampleSpec`, or the example at [the funsuite doc](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite) and see what error you get?

Comment: I just ran the test, it actually works.  But the warning message just can't go away

Comment: I run into the same situation as @PhilipChao. Runs but warning message stays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem and invalidating the caches/restarting IntelliJ fixed it.

Comment: well this was frustrating. I guess intelliJ is trading accuracy for efficiency.